# Safe area resizes itself

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, xcode-storyboard

I was trying to make a copy of `iOS` calculator layout, I created a vertical `stackView` and tried to constraint it to the safe area.

But instead of resizing my stack view to fit the constraint, it changed the safe area. **How can I make it so that the stack view resizes itself to fit the constraint and not the other way round?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its bug in xcode, remove all constraints then add from outer view first,it will be fixed

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful and solved my issue with a scrollView To be more specific, I had to remove all the constraints on the View, ScrollView, and other subviews and re-add them from the View down.